# New Relic: what does “Other” mean on the transaction chart?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

I’m wondering what does “Other” mean on this chart:

[image: transaction chart the chart]

It’s a Rails app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case, here’s the response I got from NewRelic support:

> The "Other" you are seeing in your Transactions is an aggregate of whatever is not in the top 5 segments of your transaction. If you click on the "Show all segments" link (please see the screenshot I attached), it will show you everything that encompasses the segments that are listed in "Other".

Got it.